# Three null characters after start of string in Lua bytecode?

Tags: lua, bytecode

I'm reading up on Lua bytecode. I understand that strings begin with the length of it, then the string is stored. The string then is ended by a null character. However, I'm having an issue. It says the string length is 124, including the null character at the end. However, there are three null characters preceding the string (after the length). This makes the actual length of the string 127.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thank you.

Comment: Does it happen for every string? Maybe some code would help.

Comment: I believe the string is the source name in the top level function (because it seems to be located there), but the string is the actual source of the bytecode. I can show you the bytecode if you'd like.

Comment: Including some hexdump of the bytecode would surely help, and not just me.

Comment: Here's the bytecode: https://hastebin.com/pizeyasejo. I'm not able to dump it right now because I'm on my phone, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bytecode you've posted starts with

```
\27\76\117\97\81\0\1\4\4\4\8\0\124\0\0\0...
```

or in hex

```
0000000: 1b4c 7561 5100 0104 0404 0800 7c00 0000  .LuaQ.......|...
0000010: 3d70 7269 6e74 2828 2727 292e 6475 6d70  =print(('').dump
```

The length of the string is not a single byte, it's the four bytes `7c00 0000`.

In general, the number of bytes used to represent the length of a string is the second `04` in the first line, at offset 8.

See [luaU_header](https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lundump.c.html#luaU_header) in the code.

Comment: Ohh, that makes much more sense. Thank you very much!